# How to force RadioGroup to select only one RadioButton at a time programatically?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-radiogroup

I am designing customize form programmatically where user can put a question and can add multiple options using radio buttons. I have taken RadioGroup and i am adding radio buttons in it. But while selecting i want only one radio button get selected at a time. How to implement it programmatically. Please help me..

Here is my code

```
final RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(getApplicationContext());
radioGroup.setId(1);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

RadioButton radioButtonView = new  RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
radioButtonView.setId(i++);
radioButtonView.setText(addnew);

radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView, p);
loption.addView(radioGroup, p);
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: pls provide some code of what you've tried and what is not working for you

Comment: What is the problem in your implementation right now?if you have tried anything programmatically

Comment: So, are you creating a new `RadioGroup` for every `RadioButton`? If all the `RadioButton`s go into the same `RadioGroup`, you should get the behaviour you are looking for?  Or are the code snippet from multiple places in your code?

Comment: *radioButtonView.setId(i++);* where is **`i`** anyway? are you using this whole code inside a for loop?

Comment: I have added radio buttons in radio group. Right now i can select multiple radio buttons. But i want only one radio button to be selected at at time.

Comment: Could you show us the surrounding code as well? I think what you need to do is to keep a reference to the `RadioGroup` of all the other `RadioButton`s and when you want to add a new `RadioButton`, simply add it to that `RadioGroup`

Comment: Thanks... i got my error..by mistake i am creating radiogroup everytime..that's why its not working properly..Anyways Thnks..I will try it out..

Comment: No problem :) It would be nice if you could mark my answer as the solution if it did indeed work. The same goes for all the questions you have asked earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are making a new `RadioGroup` for every `RadioButton`.

You should add every new `RadioButton` to the same `RadioGroup`. The `RadioGroup` will then make sure only one `RadioButton` can be selected at the time.

Answer (score 3):

```
 @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged  " + buttonView.getId());
        mRadioGroup.clearCheck();
        if (isChecked) {
            mRadioGroup.check(buttonView.getId());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the same problem when I insert LinearLayout to put the radiobuttons in a grid.

I solved this way.
Considering that we have more RadioGroups, we know the RadioButton that was pressed. For this reason, just remove the listener from all of your RadioGroups and then deselect all the RadioButtons, resetting onCheckedChangeListener to your RadioGroup.

This is my code:

```
onCheckedChangeListener= new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int i) {
            clearAllRadioButton();
            ((RadioButton) binding.getRoot().findViewById(i)).setChecked(true);
            resetListenerRadioGroup();
        }
    };

    onCheckedChangeListener2 = new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int i) {
            clearAllRadioButton();
            ((RadioButton) binding.getRoot().findViewById(i)).setChecked(true);
            resetListenerRadioGroup();
        }
    };


    binding.rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener);
    binding.rg2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener2);



private void clearAllRadioButton() {
    binding.rg2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    binding.rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    binding.failed.setChecked(false);
    binding.draft.setChecked(false);
    binding.sent.setChecked(false);
    binding.inbox.setChecked(false);
}

private void resetListenerRadioGroup(){
    binding.rg2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener2);
    binding.rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener);
}
```

*do not use the radioButton's clearCheck () because it does not respond well when resetting listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out it will work for you:

First Get RadioButton:

```
RadioButton radioBalls = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioGameInPlayBalls);
RadioButton radioTime = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioGameInPlayTime);
radioBalls.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
radioTime.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

Now in `@overide method:`

```
 @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean c) {
        switch (buttonView.getId()) {
        case R.id.radioGameInPlayBalls:
            if (radioTime.isChecked() && c) {
                radioBalls.setChecked(false);
                return;
            }
            radioBalls.setEnabled(c);
        break;
    case R.id.radioGameInPlayTime:
        if (radioBalls.isChecked() && c) {
            radioTime.setChecked(false);
            return;
        }
        radioTime.setEnabled(c);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check a radio button using RadioGroup, not radio button directly. Below, I populate radio group from list of options and get the radio button id of option to be checked and check the corresponding button after populating radio group. Same goes if you determine the checked option by index.

```
int checkedId = -1; 

for(JsonElement option : options){

    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getContext());

    radioGroup.addView(radioButton);

    if(checkedOptionId.equals(id)){
        checkedId = radioButton.getId();
    }
}

radioGroup.check(checkedId);
```